# number of substrings in same position with same contents

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, substrings, linear-complexity

`L1` and `L2` are two lists which only consist of `X`'s and `Y`'s. `L1` and `L2` have the same length.

How many sublists of `L1` contain the same number of `X`'s as the sublist of `L2` in the same position? The empty sublist is not counted.

For example:

1. `L1` = `X`
   `L2` = `Y`
   => return `0`
2. `L1` = `Y, Y`
   `L2` = `Y, Y`
   => return `3`
3. `L1` = `Y, X, Y`
   `L2` = `X, Y, X`
   => return `2`
4. `L1` = `Y, Y, X, X`
   `L2` = `X, X, Y, Y`
   => return `2`

A brute-force approach would have time complexity `O(n^2)`. I think (but I am not sure) there's an `O(n)` solution, but I can't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, there is an $O(n)$ time algorithm for this.

Let $L(i,j)$ be the substring of the string $L$ from index $i$ to $j$, and let $|L|_X$ be the number of $X$'s in $L$. Consider that the number of substrings ending on an index $j$ with the same number of $X$'s in both strings is equal to the number of indices $i$ (with $i<j$) for which $$|L_1(1,i)|_X - |L_2(1,i)|_X = |L_1(1,j)|_X - |L_2(1,j)|_X$$
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this helps.